Grid puzzle must be solved with one continuous line

You must draw one straight continuous line that goes through all the yellow circles without crossing or touching the purple circles, without incline and without jumping over any circle.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

One continuous straight line seemingly cannot pass through each of a 2-D arrangement of yellow cells, unless perhaps the board is wrapped around a cylinder, in which case the line won't be straight.
